# Conditional selection from two different objects with same members

Tags: c#, design-patterns

what I'm trying to do is better explained with some code:

Here I have two classes (more precisely DataTables inside a dataset, but I'll rather describe this as class notation):

```
    class A {
       public aType varA;
       public bType varB;
       public cType varC;
    }

    class B {
       public aType varA;
       public bType varB;
       public cType varC;
       public dType varD;
    }
```

and these tables are defined by a variable named ***varSelect***:

```
    A varnameA = (varSelect == 1) ? ABuilder() : null;
    B varnameB = (varSelect == 2) ? BBuilder() : null;
```

and inside the code I have to use something like :

```
   if((varSelect == 1 && varnameA.varA == true) || 
      (varSelect == 2 && varnameB.varA == true)
   { 
       ... 
   }
```

As you see, It does the same thing, but they have some different properties, but I'll mostly use the same class members for the checks. How could I design something like this?

**Note:** Think as B is a newer version of class A. But some of the code will have to continue using A as their data source.

Comment: Whenever you have a *finite* known set of concrete classes that you need to access in a polymorphic way, the [Visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) can be most helpful.

Comment: I tried interfacing both elements until I realized they are actually  datatables of different datasets.

Comment: Looking & trying to understand the visitor pattern now.

Comment: Nope, using `dynamic` typed variable is easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encapsulation and inheritance can help to solve this problem.

```
class Data {
    // Common properties
    public aType varA;
    public bType varB;
    public cType varC;
}

class A extends Data {
    // other properties
}

class B extends Data {
    public dType varD;
    // other properties
}

class DataTable {
    Data data;
    public DataTable(int selector) {
        if (selector == 1) {
            // data will contain table A
        } else if (selector == 2) {
            // data will contain table B
        }
    }

    public boolean isVarA() {
        return data.varA;
    }
}
```

So when we need to check varA, we no longer need to remember which data table was selected.

```
DataTable dataTable = new DataTable(1); // varSelect = 1
//...
//...
//...
if (dataTable.isVarA() == true) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Yes, I've thought of it, but my design was not compatible for extending and overriding, and it's not suitable for a rewrite, so I wrote a wrapper class which includes both of the types and returns selective objects.